# how to use button as link in material-ui react with out underline and change color text?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I just made a page, and use link wrapped button, but problem is when i do that, button text have underline

[Like this(log out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8du4.png)

so my question is, how to make a button router in react and not change anything in button, just add action with button, click it, and it done, i also do it with function but it show  [error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nifxQ.png)

weird is when i run on sandbox it not have that error
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-gould-olgow

here my code in local

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import './studentHome.css'
import ExitToAppIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExitToApp';
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};
const logout=()=>{
    this.props.history.push("/home");
}
function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            Hệ thống thi ABC-ONLINE
          </Typography>
          <ExitToAppIcon/>
          <Link to="/"></Link>
          <Button color="inherit" onClick>Log Out</Button>

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

in my local, i copy the same code as codesandbox and it show error, i don't know why, but use link, it have underline text,please help, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [react-router-dom Link (LinkAnchor)](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js) uses an `<a>` Tag, which has underline per default.

It should work if you add `textdecoration: none` to the `<Link>` Tag:

```
<Link to="/" style="text-decoration: none">
    <Button color="inherit" onClick>Log Out</Button>
</Link>
```

*(Note that Browsers might behave differently, but this solution should work for all, to my knowledge)*

Comment: If you get a error saying style must be an object, use 
```<Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>```

Answer (score 0):

1) maybe you have a global css that cause of underline on button text, 
check your all css files,

2) you can use chrome F12 then Ctrl+Shift+C and select your button and see all css effected on your button

Answer (score 0):

you can use useNavigate hook,

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
return <Button onClick={()=>navigate('/home')} children="Home"/>
```

don't forget to import hook

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```